# How to analyze mono crash blob files

Tags: c#, linux, crash, mono, blob

I have a C# Windows forms application written in .NET full framework that is compiled on Windows and runs on a Linux machine with mono 6.12. Sometimes the application "freezes", there is no response from GUI, the process is still loaded in memory, but a mono crash file is generated (Example: mono_crash.mem.18803.1.blob). Do you know how can I open this file, how to analyze its contents? I am assuming that this file would be useful in the troubleshooting process to identify the root cause that is causing the application to freeze.

Comment: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/telemetry/#symbolication-and-aggregation